# post acces for guests / unregistered users only

Tags: users, user-access

is there a way to restrict complete posts/pages to be viewed by guest (unregistered) users only, hide them from subscribers/logged in users? These posts shouldn't show up in category archive pages for logged in users.

I did'nt find a plugin, only the other way around. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need custom code for this. Understanding how to create custom queries via WP_Query() will be immensely helpful. You will also need to modify the 'perm' parameter for WP_Query() to change the results based on user permissions.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Permission_Parameters

If the native WP_Query parameters still don't give you exactly what you're looking for you may need a custom filter to run after the query to remove posts from the result set based on an is_user_logged_in() check.